Provide connectivity between Azure Data Factory and Databse on Internal Network
We have a PostgreSQL database hosted in AWS, which is configured with a private IP / connected via VPN to our private network; so from VMs hosted in Azure on VNets peered with our VHub we can access this AWS hosted database entirely within our private network.
Our BI team want to pull data from this AWS hosted PostgreSQL DB.  This could be done by setting up a self-hosted integration runtime on a VM in our Azure instance.  However, we want to avoid managing VMs if this is not required.
It's not entirely clear from the documentation, but it seems that by adding a private endpoint to our ADF (thus connecting it to a vnet that's part of our private network) and enabling Managed Virtual Network on the AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime (e.g. as described here) we should be able to connect to resources on our internal network.
However, when we add a Linked Service of type Postgres and hit Test Connection we get the below error:
The value of the property '' is invalid: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'.
Value does not fall within the expected range.

If we try the same using the Postgres (Legacy) connection we get:
ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC PostgreSQL Wire Protocol driver]Connection refused. Verify Host Name and Port Number.

Placing a VM on the same VNet as our ADF's private endpoint and running test-netconnection confirms that we can reach the target DB on port 5432.  When testing from the VM our firewall's AzFwNetworkRule table shows the connection with Action as Allow; confirming the connection attempt's success.  When we connect from the ADF though nothing shows in our FW's logs (if it was blocked we'd see Action as Deny, so not seeing anything implies that the traffic isn't going via the FW, which implies that the connection isn't coming from the same VNet).
Have I misunderstood how the private endpoint for an ADF works / is there a way to grant ADF access to our internal network without hosting IR in a VM that we have to then manage, or is the only way to get connectivity into our private network via the self-hosted IR solution?

These errors may be caused by issues with the firewall rules or the connection string. To troubleshoot the issue, you can check if the connection is being blocked by the firewall by checking the firewall's logs. You can also try modifying the connection string to include the private IP address of the PostgreSQL database.

Thanks @PratikLad; this wasn't caused by FW or NSG.  I'd checked for such things and also connections from the VM in the same VNet worked (this was a new VNet so there would have been no preexisting rules for specific IPs in its range).  The issue seems to be that ADF doesn't use the private endpoint for outbound traffic.  I'm not clear on what it is used for though; maybe just so SHIR can talk back to ADF without going over the public internet?
